Can not communicate with local modbus server from external client device
I have a Windows PC running two server apps. One of the servers are Bacnet SCADA server which uses port 47808 over UDP. Other server is Modbus 0TCP server which uses port 502 over TCP. And there is one external device which tries to communicate with those servers. Setup is such as:

Device communicates with Bacnet server without problems. But cant get data from modbus server. When I try to communicate with Modbus server from a local client on the same PC, there is no problem. But it doesnt work between PC and Device.
To overcome this problem, I tried several things.
I added a new IP to same adapter with IP aliasing.
I added a new lan adapter.
I shutdown bacnet server , only modbus server left on PC
I allowed 502 port in inbound rules. etc.
None of these worked. I really need a helping hand here with any considerable suggestions.

Make sure "Network interface" is set to "All interfaces", or at least not "localhost only". You should be able to see it with netstat -an, make sure there is a line showing port 502 is listening, like TCP  0.0.0.0:502  0.0.0.0:0  LISTENING. If there is only a localhost entry like 127.0.0.1:502, then you may need to update the config

I see that line. In Addition I see "TCP    [::]:502               [::]:0                 LISTENING".  How to set "Network interface" to "All interfaces"?

forgot to mention and I edited my question accordingly. There are two lan interfaces on my PC. Other interface is just used to supply internet to PC over a 4G router.

[::]:502 is IPv6 - is there an IPv4 entry too? "How to set" depends on what software you're using - for example, this one has a gui: https://docs.n3uron.com/docs/modbus-server-configuration, but modbus is just a protocol.
